https-post request using requests in micropython on esp32s3
I'm trying to write to the Mongodb database.  When I make the request, I get the error HTTP error: BadStatusLine: [].  i am using ESP32S3 with Micropython v1.23.0.
my code:
import json
import requests

def insert_one(data:list = []) -> None:
        try:
            # Need to substitute from DATA API
            url = "https://eu-central-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-zjbrnke/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne"
            headers = {"api-key": "TOKEN"}
            payload = {
            "dataSource": "Cluster0",
            "database": "main",
            "collection": "main",
            "document": {'teste': 'test'},
            }

            print("sending...")

            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload), timeout=20)

            print("Response: (" + str(response.status_code) + "), msg = " + str(response.text))

            if response.status_code == 201:
                print("Added Successfully")
            else:
                print("Error")

            # Always close response objects so we don't leak memory
            response.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'error: {e}')

I tried to change json to data, and other minor changes that did not give anything.

I think first you should add "content-type": "application/json" header and see what happen.Then try to print response object and check whether valid response code is available.

exception http.client.BadStatusLine -  A subclass of HTTPException. Raised if a server responds with a HTTP status code that we don’t understand.


I tried to add "content-type": "application/json", nothing changed. i can't print the response because it gives an error at the request stage, here: response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload), timeout=20)

@sne - did you add the content type to headers?

@JonNordby  -  do you mean "content-type": "application/json" or payload ?

@sne Actually I can't find whats happening in here.But I suspect that there is some error in your endpoint url or something because when I check this code with webhook.site It works perfectly

I think the problem is with the request-micropython library, because if i run my code through regular python, there are no problems.
